# Convert UTC to local time in date field

Tags: theming, 8, datetime

I have a content type with a date field, which I convert to a specific date format in a preprocess function:

```
$variables['date'] =
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($variables['node']->field_datum->date->getTimestamp(), 'long_date_without_time');
```

But as Germany is one hour ahead, a date like 2015-03-31 23:01:08 UTC converts to 1. April 2015. How can I convert this to our local time?

EDIT: I already set the correct timezone in the UI. And I just saw that the wrong dates are only shown when I set my system time between 11pm and 1 am...

Comment: Just a side note here, but your should really be using the field formatters / render system instead of in a preprocess.  Timezone may not end up in the cache context here, so you may encounter weirdness b/c caching problems.

Comment: I want to display the date before the page title and this is not possible with the normal field display...

Answer (score 0):

The date formatter service automatically converts it to whatever time zone you selected when you installed the Drupal site, `admin/config/regional/settings`.

Also, if you allow users to set their own timezone in `user/1/edit`, it would use that time.

So either you need to change the timezone in `admin/config/regional/settings` and/or in `user/1/edit`

Comment: I already had set on both sites the correct timezones. And I just saw that the wrong dates are only shown when I set my system time between 11pm and 1 am - this is really weird...

Comment: If a TZ isn't supplied to DateFormatter, it will pull it from the PHP `date_default_timezone_get()`.  If you use the field formatters, it honors the Drupal settings via `drupal_get_user_timezone()` or the override setting.

Comment: Also, the config whether or not a user can use their own TZ is on admin/config/regional/settings.  If that is set, then they can pick an option on their own user edit page.

Comment: As I already said, the correct timezone is already set in the UI

Comment: Which city or town do u live in and which timezone did u select?

Comment: So you selected [`Europe/Berlin`](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=berlin+time) as your time zone and you live in Berlin?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you answered. I don't live in Berlin, but in the same country and time zone.

Comment: Sorry forgot to use the @0711master so you get notified. What city/town do you live in then?